# How to use \ref with automatic parenthesis, text and the refnumber? aka: (Siehe S. 3)

Tags: cross-referencing, pageref

I have a small inconvenience with referencing within my document. I would like `\pageref{sample}` to not show "7" but instead (Look p.7). At the moment I do it by hand but I would like to automate also that part.
The code I use at the moment is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,toc=bibliography,toc=listof,parskip=yes]{scrreprt}u sepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Wird u.a. f\"ur das Trennen von W\"ortern  mit Umlauten genutzt.
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel} % deutsche Bezeichnungen und Worttrennung… 
    

\begin{document}

Important part \label{sample}
\\\ %to avoid the questionmarks
what i get:\pageref{sample}

what it want: (look p.\pageref{sample})

\end{document}
```

[image: the result]

I have also tried:

```
\documentclass[12pt,toc=bibliography,toc=listof,parskip=yes]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefformat{page}{(Siehe S.)}   

\begin{document}

Important part \label{sample}
\\\
kinda what i want, but now with the number:\cpageref{sample}

\end{document}
```

the result is "Siehe S." without pagenumber.

Then I tried:

```
\documentclass[12pt,toc=bibliography,toc=listof,parskip=yes]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Wird u.a. f\"ur das Trennen von W\"ortern  mit Umlauten genutzt.
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel} % deutsche Bezeichnungen und Worttrennung… 
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefformat{page}{(Siehe S.\pageref{})}

\begin{document}

Important part  \label{sample}
\\\\
kinda what i want, but now with the number: \cpageref{sample}

\end{document}
```

However, that just gives me question marks (aka: "(Siehe S.??)").
At this point I have no more ideas - does anyone know how I can do this please? I'm using MiKTeX with TeXmaker if it is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cleveref` manual explains, that the format of `\crefformat`

> should contain three arguments, `#1`, `#2`
> and `#3`. The first argument is the formatted version of the label counter (e.g.
> `\theequation`). The other two are used to mark the beginning and end of the
> part of the cross-reference that forms the hyperlink when the `hyperref` package
> is used, and must appear in that order

So a possible definition would be:

```
\crefformat{page}{#2(\seename\ \pagename~#1)#3}
```

Here is use a somehow different definition:

```
\documentclass[12pt,toc=bibliography,toc=listof,parskip=yes]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% Not needed since LaTeX 2018-04-01
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[main=english,ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefformat{page}{#2(\seename\ \shortpagename~#1)#3}
\newcaptionname{ngerman}{\shortpagename}{S.}% see KOMA-Script manual
\newcaptionname{english}{\shortpagename}{p.}% see KOMA-Script manual
\begin{document}

Important part \label{sample}

kinda what i want, but now with the number: \cpageref{sample}

\selectlanguage{ngerman}
Und in Deutsch wäre es: \cpageref{sample}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot, exactly what i was searching for!

I remember reading and trying out that part of the manual but only got major errors which would not even have an output. sometimes Latex is just a hinche too logical for me ^^